# CountDownTimer onTick does not work within service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I am trying to create an android app widget with a countdown timer.  I have a service that makes an HTTP request, and then a countdown timer which updates the UI of the app widget (with data from HTTP request).  For whatever reason, the countdown timer onTick will not tick inside of the service.  I am not getting any sort of error..

Here is my code:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("URL_TO_CALL")
            .build()

    //Make API call
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare()
                Looper.loop()
            }


            //Create countdown timer object
            var ctd = object : CountDownTimer(countdownTime, 5000) {

                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    //Nothing in here is being called

                }

            }

            Handler().postDelayed({
                ctd.start()
            }, 500)

        }
})

return Service.START_STICKY

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, did you find a solution for that?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you put in WAKE_LOCK?

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = null;
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        mWakeLock.acquire();
```

and in onDestroy

```
if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
```

Now, this is if your aplication is getting closed when you turn off your screen